# Update Plugin Without Overwriting Custom Settings

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, the-content, excerpt

My plugin uses the code below that has uid="x" in it that requires the user to edit the plugin and set "x" to their user id, such as uid="420971". Whenever I release an update to the plugin and the user downloads it, the update overwrites this setting because the update has the generic u="x" in it.  How can I save the user's personal uid and apply it to the updated plugin?

```
add_filter('the_content', 'the_plugin');

function the_plugin($content) {
  global $add_the_script;

  $content_add_on = '<div class="ACME_STATS" uid="x"></div>';
  $theContent = $content.$content_add_on;
  $add_the_script = true;

  return ($theContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the uid in an [option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). Use the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to create an admin page to manage the option.

Comment: The keywords "option", "settings API", and "admin page" tapped into good examples from WordPress and Google. Thanks.